# Mule Deployment properties file

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have seen some strange behaviour in Mule Application. I created a sample mule project(created flows) and opened mule-deploy.properties file "config.resources" value is empty.

But the same above mentioned key value is getting updated with "configuration xml file name" when i run my mule project.

Is this the behaviour or any updates need to be done.

Can some clarify?

Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some known issues/features around mule-deploy.properties and Mule Studio.

Currently it is expected that when running your project from Mule Studio that mule-deploy.properties-config.resources is automatically populated with all your configuration files.

There are some open issues on this here: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-3297 that you can vote on.

Comment: Hi ryan, Thanks for the reply. I dont have access to the link (mule soft jira). So i can assume this issue is going to be resolved in next mule studio releases?

Comment: You should be able to login with your Mule community login if you have one(for the forum etc.) or you should be able to sign up here:https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/secure/Signup!default.jspa. The issue is still open, but theres a target release for 3.5-Everest.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run the mule application it will automatically updated with the configuration file by default if you have only one main configuration file.But If you are using more configuration files in your application you should manually add all the filenames to the config.properties key separated by comma before run the application.